# Am I using keyup correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, keyup

This is an excerpt from a js file

```
        $searchBox.keyup(function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) { //enter
                if(currentResult > -1) {
                    var result = $searchResults.find('tr.result a')[currentResult];
                    window.location = $(result).attr('href');
                }
            } else if(event.keyCode === 38) { //up
                if(currentResult > 0) {
                    currentResult--;
                    renderCurrent();
                }
            } else if(event.keyCode === 40) { //down
                if(lastResults.length > currentResult + 1){
                    currentResult++;
                    renderCurrent();
                }
            } else {
                var query = $searchBox.val();
                if (lastQuery !== query) {
                    currentResult = -1;
                    if (query.length > 2) {
                        self.search(query);
                    } else {
                        self.hideResults();
                    }
                    if(self.hasFilter(getCurrentApp())) {
                        self.getFilter(getCurrentApp())(query);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

This means that it should only perform the action if the "Enter", "Up" or "Down" keys are pressed, right?  Because the search start happening as soon as any key is pressed.

I also tried changing searchBox.keyup to searchBox.change but that messed up how something else was working.

Comment: you have the `else` condition too. if you're pressing any other key then the `else` condition will fire and will start searching.

Comment: after all your `else if` statements, you land on the last code block, which seems to create the variable `query` from `$searchBox.val();` and if the length of that query is greater than 2, it appears you kick off the `self.search(query);` routine.

Comment: Thank you, I knew there was something I was staring at that just wasn't clicking with me on what I needed to see.

Comment: you're most welcome :)